# Fire javascript event through chrome extension api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

1. I used below code for https://www.google.com.
2. The id is set to the button correctly.
3. And second script, console.log() is printed correctly.
4. But click() event is not working. HOW TO FIRE THIS EVENT?

.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
    code: `document.evaluate('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.setAttribute("id", "btn_search");`
});

chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
    code: `console.log(document.getElementById("btn_search"));document.getElementById("btn_search").click();`
});
```

Comment: Your code runs correctly in my case. How about to give several ms delays and test.

Comment: I gave 5000 ms, after 5 sec console.log() printed correctly. but click() event is not fired. @jaromanda X did you fire the click() event??

Comment: All I did was make your code (a little more) readable -

Comment: Yes, It is working except google search button :D I could not understand why it is ..

Comment: Make sure the search box is **not** empty when you attempt the click. Otherwise, the click has no effect.